# How to adjust pages in RMarkdown pdf file?

Tags: r-markdown

[image]I am creating a pdf document using RMarkdown in RStudio. The Knit do not create properly the fourth  page. The page number on the foot still in the mean of on list at the botom of the page, and the text "desapears", even a new page is created but the text is not rendered.

I have just rolling back to 1.8

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_version("rmarkdown", version = "1.8")
```

Is there any adjust in RStudio to avoid this issue ?

HTML and WORD make the report correctly using the same .Rmd file

[image: text overlaping the new page]

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: My be something wrong when include pictures using the sentence: ![imagen](pics/02.png)